# Form load options in Infopath designer 2007

Tags: infopath, forms-services

In Infopath designer 2007, where do I find “Form Load” Options (like the one which is present in Data connections in infopath designer 2010). please Indicate the location.

Answer (score 2):

Open the InfoPath Form in Design view.

1) Go to Tools -> Form Options.

2) Select Category 'Open and Save'.

3) There is a section called 'Open behavior', where you can set Rules. These Rules are fired when the Form is opened. This is similar to Rules specified in "Form Load" option in InfoPath 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267334(v=office.12).aspx

It gives all the instructions step by step. :)